# restore fails due to insufficent disk space

Tags: backup, windows-sbs-2008, restore, hyper-v-server-2012

I'm trying to test my SBS 2008 backup by restoring to a vm on a Hyper-V server.  The SBS is a physical machine.

I created two vhdx each at 1TB in (fixed) size, which is larger than the actual disks which are 233 and 466 GB each.  The restore fails almost immediately with this message:

[image]

The physical server has two other disks which are not backed up if that matters.  I'm starting the restore by booting the vm from the SBS 2008 CD and going to the complete system restore option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try creating fixed size VHDX files. I would suggest creating one of 250GB and the second of 500GB.

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks for the tip, but they are fixed sized vhdxs.  I forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: What Windows OS is Hyper-V running on? The default virtual disk in Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012 is dynamically expanding. You have to convert it to fixed size if you want a fixed size disk. Have you done that? When you inspect the disk what type does it show?

Comment: Hyperv 2012.  They are fixed disks I created with the new-vhd command in powershell.  I just confirmed this using hyperv manager.

Comment: OK, just trying to be thorough. Have you looked at the physical files to confirm they're the size you configured?

Comment: @joeqwerty yes, they are indeed 1TB in size.

Comment: @Andy you may also wish to take a [look at this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f15bfe2f-e265-479a-afa3-f055530c97f5/windows-server-backup-0x80042407-seriously?forum=winserverfiles).  Were the original disks 1TB in total size?

Comment: @JamesSantiago there are drives I didn't recreate, but these were also not backed up.  Is that what you're suggesting the problem is?

Comment: @Andy, why not try to create the disks with a true size (i.e 233 and 466GB)?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is make sure the recovery environment is actually seeing your hard drives.

Open Command Prompt and run `diskpart`.  The command `list disk` will show what disks windows sees.  If they aren't showing up, either the VM is configured incorrectly, or you need to load some extra storage drivers first.  I believe the restore wizard prompts you to load drivers at some point.

Also, ensure "Format and repartition disks" is selected, or that the disks are blank (delete all partitions).

Comment: Ive already done those things, and the restore doesn't give you any options it says it will repatriation and format.

Comment: Can you put up a screenshot of the output of diskparts list disk command?  Maybe that will show something else odd.

Comment: Ive already removed as I have given up (although I would like to try again in the future).  I didn't see anything wrong and I did create partitions and format the disks.

Comment: Did you try it both ways - with the disks partitioned and formatted, and another try with the disks completely blank?

Comment: Yes, I only tried to partition and format in order to fix this issue.